# Python function to return JSON data from web site

Tags: python

I'm trying my hand at Python and was wondering if the below example makes sense. Basically I'm trying to pull back business name based on an id but keep getting an error message saying NameError: name 'assert_equal' is not defined. I think it's not correct because I'm missing something around the assert_equal lines of the code. Suggestions are greatly appreciated. :-)

```
import requests
import json
import assert_equal

def get_details_by_id(id):
url = 'http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Help/Api/GET-Establishments-id'
customheader = {'x-api-version': '2'}
r = requests.get('http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Establishments/%d' %id, headers=customheaders)
return r.json()['BusinessName']

assert_equal(get_establishment_by_id(123456), '123 Over Here Street')
assert_equal(get_establishment_by_id(987654), '456 Over There Street')

print('All tests successfully passed')
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the code isn't correct? If yes, you should tell us about it.

Comment: Hi, sorry, the error message I was getting was assert_equal not defined. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the `url` and `id` you defined.

```
requests.get('url/id', ...
```

should be

```
requests.get('{}/{}'.format(url, id), ...
```

If using Python 3.6:

```
requests.get(f'{url}/{id}', ...
```

Next time please provide the error you are getting.